# How do I set two cookies in headers using URLFetchApp

Tags: cookies, google-apps-script, urlfetch

Working with an old SOAP api.
When I login, it returns *two* cookies.
Both cookies must be included in the headers of subsequent api calls.
I can't figure out how to set two cookies in URLFetchApp.
Any help?

Here's what I have so far (typical):

```
tempHeader = {'Cookie':myCookieString1};
tempParameters = {"method":"GET", "headers":tempHeader};
```

(etc, I skipped irrelevant stuff)

```
tempResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(targetURL, tempParameters);
```

Since tempHeader is an object, I can't add two "Cookie" properties with the same name.
I tried variations of giving it an array of objects, etc, but none of that worked.

Comment: According to MDN, the syntax for including multiple cookies is -  Cookie: name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3 .  [MDN - Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) Have you tried that?  Also, "doesn't work" could mean a lot of different things. What's the server response? Any errors being thrown?

Comment: Hi Anton, yes, I tried that, doesn't work:


`var tempHeader = {'Cookie':'jsession=somesession;ckie2=someotherSutff'};`


Here's the debug log from GAS.  

`{headers={Cookie=jsession=somesession;ckie2=someotherSutff}, method=post, payload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

All the server tells me is "invalid session".

Comment: Were these cookies previously set using the Cookie-Set header in server response?

Comment: Also from MDN [Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) - The Cookie HTTP header contains stored cookies previously sent by the server with the Set-Cookie header

Comment: Btw, web apps in Google App Script can’t read request headers. You’ll need to spin up a server for that

Comment: Anton, here's the flow:
- I send a login request
- Server returns a login confirmation with two attached cookies
- I grab the two cookies from the response.  (Yes, I can get them in GAS)
- Now when I want to send further requests, I must attach both of those two cookies in the headers.

Comment: There should be a space after `;` for the header to be valid. `var tempHeader = {'Cookie':'jsession=somesession; ckie2=someotherSutff'};`

Comment: TheMaster:

Thanks, I've just tested that.  It's not working (server is returning "serialization" error).

When I look at the debug output, I think this is probably why:
The actual cookie content already has several semicolons in it:

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABC123; Path=stuff; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: NSC_stuff;path=/;secure;httponly

So, when I do ^, the debug is:

{headers={Cookie=JSESSIONID=ABC123; Path=stuff; HttpOnly; NSC_stuff;path=/;secure;httponly}

UrlFetchApp can't separate the two cookies from each other, so it acts like it's all one.  Can I escape the semicolons?

Comment: It seems UrlFetchApp should give me a way to put "cookie 1" and "cookie 2" in the headers object.

Comment: You only need to send `var tempHeader = {'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=ABC123; NSC_stuff=test'};` or ``var tempHeader = {'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=ABC123; NSC_stuff=test; '};``. However, it doesn't seem like the api expects another server interaction: HttpOnly directive means the cookie is to be sent only from a browser.

Comment: The browser always sends all cookies in a single cookie header combined. Note:Using ``@``  notifies us (like`@Anton`).

Comment: OK Themaster, I did that, and it seems I'm pretty close.  New debug:

{headers={Cookie=JSESSIONID=stuff; NSC_fubqftusz-ena=stuff; , X-Forwarded-For=173.10.251.42}, method=post, payload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Server still throws "deserialziation error".  The x-forwarded-for with a comma in front of it seems unlikely to be helpful...  and I'm not inserting that... ??

Comment: Did you try `var tempHeader = {'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=ABC123; NSC_stuff=test'};`( without semicolon at the end )? Could you use "run" button in the editor instead of a button in a sheet or elsewhere? That should remove the x-forwarded header and your ip address. Use @TheMaster to notify me.

Comment: Deserialization error means your xml is malformed. Cookies has nothing to do with that. I believe this question is answered. For other errors please ask a new question providing relevant details. See [ask] and [mre]

Comment: OK you're right.  I'm running the script from the GAS dev page.  When I run it with the Debug button it includes the x-forward phrase; when I run it with the Run button it omits that.  (PITA)

Reviewing the xml again for the deserialization issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to TheMaster who gave me the right answer.

```
var tempHeader = {'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=ABC123; NSC_stuff=test; '}
// this represents the *two* cookies I need to send, separated by semicolon, and ended by a semicolon and a space.

tempParameters = {"method":"GET", "headers":tempHeader}; 
myResult = UrlFetchApp.fetch(targetURL, tempParameters);
```

Comment: yeah, I did, thanks. As you said, it's in the SOAP payload, not in the headers.  SOAP is painful.

Comment: I must login for voting your answer.